# What is the right way to export videos with different FPS?

Tags: video, after-effects, premiere, animation-rendering, export

I know about rendering and exporting. But it's about some video clips having different FPS. For example, my current practice project has:

**1.** Motion Title (29.97 FPS)

**2.** Video clip 23.976 FPS

**3.** Other video clips with 24/23.976 FPS.

I have edited all of them in **After Effects**. And I'm going to export them as .mov/.avi (lossless) and finally export as compressed format (.MP4) using **Premiere Pro**.

For this, I'm supposed to change Pr sequence settings to 29.97 FPS and drag all clips into it.

Now question is: Would it affect the quality of the clips that don't match with 29.96 FPS?

Another question: Is it better to compress them individually with their respective FPS settings and COMBINE them later with some software (If such professional software exists)?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, all of your assets should be converted to the same frame rate as your final output frame rate *before* you begin editing. If you do not convert them beforehand, you may have issues with timings. Things that are supposed to be one length end up being a different length. This is especially true if you export a variable frame rate file. Suddenly a 30 second file becomes 28 seconds, or 33 seconds, or some other length. The audio and the video end at different times. Things may play right in some places, but they may be wrong if they are processed and played elsewhere.

To summarize:

1. Convert all assets to the final frame rate before editing.
2. Set your project to the correct final frame rate.
3. Do not export a mixed or variable frame rate file.

Comment: Is there any way to convert without loss of quality? What software should I use? Can Premiere Pro or After Effects do this? Like exporting in Ae as lossless format with required FPS? Secondly I don't understand your point very well. If we're exporting different FPS videos in a single project with definite FPS setting, wouldn't it mean we've converted the FPS of all videos? Or do I need to convert them before it like I've mentioned in first line of this comment?

Comment: A frame rate conversion on its own doesn't usually cause a loss of quality. A poorly executed frame rate conversion might and that's what happens when you just let the player or down stream processing software do the conversion. You can use either Premier or AE to convert the frame rate. You should use a high quality intermediate codec like DNxHD when creating assets that will later be edited. In theory having mixed frame rate assets in a single sequence shouldn't be an issue. However, I've seen it cause too many problems, so that's why I recommend converting to the target frame rate first.